# break when watched expression becomes true

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm using `visual studio code` with the `c++` extension and `gnu` debugger on ubuntu 14.04.

I'm setting a watch expression in my program, which works as expected, but I'd like to trigger the debugger to break when that condition becomes true. How can you do that with `visual studio code`? The [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_data-inspection) is pretty thin on this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you add a block that you can break at?

For example, make a condition:

```
while(true)
{
    //stuff is happening
    if(condition_happened)
    {
        std::cout<<"things happened"<<std::endl; //break here
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what I thought too

Comment: Duh, the easy way :) It didn't occur to me because the code I'm looking at uses 1-line `if` statements.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus Happens. I understand! :)